# Event keypress jquery when match a special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to processing code when user type @ like facebook tag. When user type @abc, then event is processed. This is my code:

```
$("#content").keypress(function(e) {
          var tmp = $("#content").val();
          if(tmp =="@")
          {
            console.log("It working");
          }
        });
```

UPDATING

Code like this:

```
$("#content").keypress(function(event) {
          var tmp  = $("#content").val();
          if(tmp.indexOf('@') !== -1)
          {
            console.log("It's working");
          }
        });
```

It's working when i'm typing @ with anything charater, but when i type  (space), it also working, i try to stop event when user type (space) after @anything.

Comment: Use `keyCode` to check if certain key is pressed. [jQuery: if key "someKey" pressed](//stackoverflow.com/q/8573795)

Comment: shouldn't it be tmp === '@abc' if you are detecting @abc ?

Comment: [Triggered @mention Autocomplete like Facebook, Twitter and Google+](//stackoverflow.com/q/9870650) and [Twitter/Facebook \@mention functionality with jQuery](//stackoverflow.com/q/6487625)

Comment: it's can anything string after @, like this: `@anything`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best solution for this would be:

```
$("#content").keypress(function(e) {

    if (e.which == 64) {
        console.log("It working");
    }
});
```

hope it helps!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine because the condition is:

```
if(tmp == "@")
{
    console.log("It working");
}
```

it match for only `@`. If you want to match something like `@abc` or `@def` combination kind of string then use `REGEX`

Comment: I'm updating my question, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here I make [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/c2k8twpz/) for you

```
$("#content").keypress(function(e) {
          var tmp = $("#content").val();
          if(tmp.charAt(0) ==="@")
          {
            console.log("It working");
          }
        });
```

Comment: I'm updating my question, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMOobO) .
You need to use `valuestring.charAt(0)` every time.

Comment: I'm updating my question, Thank you!

Comment: @LucyVo I have updated codepen. Please check now,that might help